# Why is java standard output not affected by '-Dfile.encoding' in windows console?

Tags: java, windows, console

I'm a Java programer from China, recently I found a strange thing that the Windows console (eg. cmd.exe) seems to be able to display the characters that are not supported by current Code Page.

Could someone please tell me why?
There is example code and test result below.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class EncodingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("jvm default charset:" + Charset.defaultCharset());
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true);
        ps.println("PrintStream测试");
        System.out.println("测试哦，就是要测试啊啊");
        System.out.println("中文测试");
        System.out.println("--------------");
    }
}
```

and here is screenshot of test result:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ82E.png)

Comment: The JVM doesn't use the `file.encoding` for console output - it asks Windows for the encoding used in the console and uses that encoding for console output.

Comment: thanks,what you've said totally make sense